# How to smooth out brush mark on wall

Tags: painting

I try to make one of my cabinet wall a chalkboard, but the roller brush was small and left quite a bit of brush mark. Does anyone know how to get it smooth out?

This is the paint mark after third coat.

[image: paint mark]

Comment: Try another coat with the paint mixed *thoroughly* and stir it up more while applying. Trick coatings like this love to separate in the can.  I just had a quart of slip-plate graphite coating where the bottom half of the can was solids, and I had to stir it for 30 minutes!)  Sometimes it'll even separate right while you're painting; zinc galvanized paint is famous for this, and you have to constantly agitate it.  Also make sure you are rolling out the roller effectively so it rolls instead of skids.

Comment: It almost looks like it’s just over rolled.  That is, rolled too thin and dry.